# TypeInitializeException on MVVM pattern

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, typeinitializeexception

`System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  Message=The type initializer for 'SmartHomeworkOrganizer.ViewModels.MainViewModel' threw an exception.
  Source=SmartHomeworkOrganizer
  TypeName=SmartHomeworkOrganizer.ViewModels.MainViewModel
  StackTrace:
       at SmartHomeworkOrganizer.ViewModels.MainViewModel..ctor()
       at SmartHomeworkOrganizer.App.OnStartup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\App.xaml.cs:line 21
       at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__0(Object unused)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object userData)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
       at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
       at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
       at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
       at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
       at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
       at System.Windows.Application.Run()
       at SmartHomeworkOrganizer.App.Main() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException: System.ArgumentException
       Message=Default value type does not match type of property 'Score'.
       Source=WindowsBase
       StackTrace:
            at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.ValidateDefaultValueCommon(Object defaultValue, Type propertyType, String propertyName, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback, Boolean checkThreadAffinity)
            at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.ValidateMetadataDefaultValue(PropertyMetadata defaultMetadata, Type propertyType, String propertyName, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)
            at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.RegisterCommon(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata defaultMetadata, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)
            at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata, ValidateValueCallback validateValueCallback)
            at System.Windows.DependencyProperty.Register(String name, Type propertyType, Type ownerType, PropertyMetadata typeMetadata)
            at SmartHomeworkOrganizer.ViewModels.MainViewModel..cctor() in C:\Users\Mohit\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\SmartHomeworkOrganizer\ViewModels\MainViewModel.cs:line 72
       InnerException:`

This bit of code throws a System.ArgumentException before the TypeInitializeException. It says: "Default value type does not match type of property Score":

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ScoreProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Score", typeof(float), typeof(MainViewModel), new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0));
```

Here is the .NET property:

```
public float Score
{
    get { return (float) GetValue(ScoreProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ScoreProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide code snippet for more elaboration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 0.0f.  0.0 is a double.

This annoyance is one reason that I almost never use floats.  The performance impact is negligible and the memory impact only matters if you're dealing with very large data sets.